# How do I prove that $f(x)=x^2-4x+3$ is injective at $(-\infty, 2)$ and $(2,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I have tried to prove that f(x) is injective at $(-\infty, 2)$ and  $(2,\infty)$ using the $f(x)=f(y)$ method. But I don't end up with $x=y$ using that method.

I there any other way to prove it?

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=(x-2)^2-1$.

Comment: Your comment is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x^2-4x=y^2-4y$. Hence $x^2-y^2-4(x-y)=0$, which means
$$(x-y)(x+y-4)=0.$$
This is true if and only if $x=y$ or $x+y-4=0$. Now if $x,y > 2$, then $x+y>4$, so the only possibility is $x=y$. Same for $x,y < 2$ (try).

Answer (score 0):

On the on the interval $(2,+\infty)$, we have
$$f(x)=f(y)\;\Rightarrow (x+y)(x-y)=4(x-y),$$
suppose that $x\neq y$, then we have
$$ x+y =4,$$
but we know that both $x,y>2$, a contradiction. Similar for the interval $(-\infty,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

This real valued function is obiously continuous and differentiable at every point in $\mathbb{R}$. $\frac{df(x)}{dx} =2x-4$. So $f'(x)>0 , x\in (2,+\infty)$ and $f'(x)<0 , x\in (-\infty,2)$. So since f is properly monotonous and coninouous in those two specific intervals, is also injective, i.e. if $x\neq y$ then $f(x)\neq f(y)$ . $\blacksquare$